# Is there a way to map same hibernate entity to multiple tables in different schemes

Tags: java, spring, entity-framework, hibernate, postgresql

This is the situation. I have a table called customer and this table is repeating among different schemes in the same database. so the problem is when i'm going to map this customer table with hibernate entity do i need to create multiple classes for specifying the schema or can i dynamically change the schema in the entity. I'm a newbie to this hibernate framework please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have more persistence unit. And use entity manager created via entity manager factory which used proper persistence unit.

In persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="pu1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
          <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:database://url1"/>
          <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="username"/>
          <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="pass"/>
...
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="pu2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
          <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:database://url12"/>
          <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="username"/>
          <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="pass"/>
...
</persistence-unit>

private static EntityManagerFactory emf1;
private static EntityManagerFactory emf2;

emf1 = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu1");
emf2 = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pu2");


emf1.createEntityManager();//Will store to database defined in pu1
emf2.createEntityManager();//Will store to database defined in pu2
```

Comment: is this is possible with using annotations